# Append to compressed file using zlib

Tags: c++, c, compression, zlib, heap-memory

Looking around I have found the question being asked, but not great answers. If this is a stackoverflow duplicate (sorry!)

My goal is to have a zlib compressed file that I append to using C/C++ at different intervals (such as a log file). Due to buffer size constraints I was hoping to avoid having to keep the entire file in memory for appending new items.

Comment: Your post  in its current form is too broad and not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: updated the question to be less vague for you by simplifying and pointing out an example might be log files.. Still can't find anything on Stackoverflow that matches and am looking into Adler's answer. Which seems to be spot on.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious The question didn't seem too broad to me. It was quite simple and specific. "How do you append to a zlib stream?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to keep something like a compressed log, appending small amounts of data each time. For that you can look at [`gzlog.h`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.h) and [`gzlog.c`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzlog.c) for an example of how to do this.

You can also look at [`gzappend`](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/gzappend.c), which appends data to a gzip file.

These are all easily adaptable to a zlib stream.

Comment: `gzappend` takes `gzip` file as an input, but what if I want to append data to zlib compressed file ? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Adler's answer was very close to what I needed, but due to already being entrenched in the zlib library and on an embedded device with limited resources I was/am stuck.

I ended up simply appending a delimiter to each section of data (ex: @@delimiter@@) and once ready to read the finished file, (different application) it seeks these sections and creates an array object of the compressed sections that are then individually decompressed.

I am still marking Adler's answer as correct, as it was useful info that will be of more help to other programmers.